# Portable modules in Asp.Net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, nuget, nuget-package

I have a module in my project that I want to share with another project in the solution. It consists of several controllers, models, and views.

I want to avoid seeing copy-pasted files.

I have done some research into this and seen some old solutions of portable areas using mvc-contrib. Does this work in MVC 4? Looks like it doesn't.

I've had a play with nuget and created a package, and it packages up the compiled stuff nicely but it copies the views into the project. What's to stop someone editing those views instead of updating the source project and repackaging?

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was looking for http://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

See [ASP.NET MVC Plugins](http://maxtoroq.github.io/2012/02/aspnet-mvc-plugins.html)......

Comment: @gibbocool You could include that in the nuget package, either as dependencies (e.g. jQuery) or as content.